What is the best statistical tool/measurement to determine correlation between four different demographics and their Likert scale responses
I have the results of a couple likert scale questions as well as demographic data (4 different
age groups of different sizes) about each response. What is the best way to determine correlation between responses and demographics?

One option is to do a hierarchical ordinal regression.

I personally would create a scoring system. If you have 5 options or so on your likert scale, you shouldn't have any trouble coming up with a system for the demographics.
It honestly seems like it could be solved simply by normalizing the data to bring it into the same range. I would start with min/max normalization.
It will change all the numbers, but preserve their relationships for correlation analysis.
